answer key, help please!
I'm working with exercise lists with answers at the end of the text. I've already researched some ways to put the answer at the end of the text, for example, using the task function. I want to maintain the formatting of my document and would like some help to find out if it is possible for me to post answers using some latex function and, at the same time, maintain the formatting of my document. I'll post a photo of what my list looks like. Here is my code:
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1.8cm]{geometry}% Margens

\usepackage{indentfirst}                % Coloca parágrafo no início texto
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}          % Linguagem português
%\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}          % Para criar anexar links
%\usepackage{lmodern}                   % Usa a fonte Latin Modern
\usepackage{multicol}                   % Texto em duas colunas
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\fixspacing}{\vspace{0pt plus 1filll}\mbox{}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\gridwidth}
\newlength{\gridheight}
\newlength{\gridstep}
\newcommand{\gridfill}[1][]{%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (grid start) at (0,0); }%
    \vfill\hfill\null%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (grid end) at (0,0); }%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, #1]
        \pgfmathsetlength{\gridstep}{\tikz@grid@x}
        \draw let \p1 = (grid start |- grid end),
        \p2 = (grid start -| grid end), 
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)}
        in \pgfextra{
            \pgfmathsetlength{\gridwidth}{int(\n1 / \gridstep) * \gridstep}
            \pgfmathsetlength{\gridheight}{int(\n2 / \gridstep) * \gridstep}
            \draw[shift={(grid start)}] (0,0) grid (\gridwidth,-\gridheight);
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

%\setlength{\columnsep}{0.7cm}          % Separação entre as colunas
%\usepackage{chemformula}               % Para escrever fórmulas químicas
%\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}         % |
%\usetikzlibrary{fit}                   % |Formatação das fórmulas químicas
%\usepackage{mol2chemfig}               % |
%\usepackage{caption}                   % Colocar caption em minipage
%\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption} %Coloca a "Figura" em negrito nas legendas
%\usepackage{microtype}                     % para melhorias de justificação
%\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}    % Paginas com as citações na bibliografia
%\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}          % Citações padrão ABNT
%\usepackage{lipsum}                        % para geração de dummy text
\usepackage{subfigure}                  % Adicionar subfiguras
%\usepackage{fontawesome}               % Fonte e simbolos
\usepackage{xcolor}                     % Mudar cor das palavras
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % Inclusão de gráficos
%\hypersetup{colorlinks = true}         % Colorir Links
%\usepackage{nomencl}                   % Lista de simbolos
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
%\usepackage{showframe}                 % Mostra margens
\usepackage{amsmath}                    % Ambiente Matemático
\usepackage{array}                      % Para colocar tabelas
\usepackage{float}                      % fixa a figura no lugar
\usepackage[a]{esvect}                  % vetor pra maiuscula
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, align=left}
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}% Use this instead of \parindent = 0pt
%\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, leftmargin=15pt, labelwidth=15pt, align=left}
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}% Use this instead of \parindent = 0pt
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage[pages=all]{background}
\backgroundsetup{placement=center,angle=58,hshift=0,vshift=0,scale=8,contents={Prof. Ulisses Moreira},color=black,opacity=0.03}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pro]{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amstext}
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\color{blue}}
\usepackage{textcomp,mathcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        
        \item (Mackenzie-SP) Numa noite de inverno, o dormitório de
        Serginho apresentava uma temperatura ambiente de 10 °C. Para não sentir frio durante a madrugada, ele esticou sobre a cama três cobertores de lã bem espessos e aguardou alguns minutos. Em seguida, deitou-se e percebeu que a cama continuava muito fria. Após certo tempo na cama, bem coberto, sentiu que o “frio passou” e que a cama estava quente. Tal fato explica-se, pois %bernoulli letra b
        
        \begin{enumerate}%[label=(\alph*)]
            \item o frio não existe e a sensação de Serginho era apenas psicológica.
            \item os cobertores não são aquecedores, mas isolantes
            térmicos. Depois de Serginho deitar-se, seu corpo aqueceu a cama. %correta
            \item a cama provavelmente não tinha lençóis de lã e, então, o calor produzido pelos cobertores foi perdido para o ambiente. Quando Serginho se deitou, interrompeu esse processo.
            \item os cobertores de lã provavelmente eram de cor clara e, por isso, demoraram muito para aquecer a cama. Após Serginho ter-se deitado, foi necessário mais algum tempo para que a cama ficasse quente.
            \item a lã utilizada para a confecção dos cobertores é um aquecedor natural muito lento e a temperatura de Serginho, de aproximadamente 37 °C, não era suficiente para aquecer a cama.
        \end{enumerate}
        \item (FUVEST-SP) Sabe-se que a temperatura do café se mantém razoavelmente constante no interior de uma garrafa térmica perfeitamente vedada. %bernoulli
        \begin{enumerate} 
            \item Qual é o principal fenômeno responsável por esse bom isolamento térmico? 
            \item O que acontece com a temperatura do café se a garrafa térmica for agitada vigorosamente? 
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    

    \centering \textbf{GABARITO}
    
    
    \raggedcolumns

        \begin{enumerate}[labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=\widthof{\ref{last-item}},itemindent=0cm,leftmargin=!]
            \item b. %#question 1
            \item  %#question 2
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item O espelhamento duplo das paredes dificulta a transferência de calor por radiação; o vácuo entre as paredes dificulta a transferência de calor por condução e convecção; a tampa inibe a transferência de calor por convecção e dificulta a condução de calor.
                \item A energia interna e a temperatura do café aumentam. O café não recebe calor de fora, mas sim trabalho realizado pela pessoa.
            \end{enumerate} 
        \end{enumerate}
        
\end{document}


Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at this guide for how to prune your code for this purpose.

Why did you delete your question and repost it? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/731291/answer-key-help-please

Have a look at the new package enumext

This is one way using the new enumext package:
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1.8cm]{geometry}% Margens

\usepackage{indentfirst}                % Coloca parágrafo no início texto
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}          % Linguagem português
%\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}          % Para criar anexar links
%\usepackage{lmodern}                   % Usa a fonte Latin Modern
\usepackage{multicol}                   % Texto em duas colunas
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\fixspacing}{\vspace{0pt plus 1filll}\mbox{}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\gridwidth}
\newlength{\gridheight}
\newlength{\gridstep}
\newcommand{\gridfill}[1][]{%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (grid start) at (0,0); }%
    \vfill\hfill\null%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (grid end) at (0,0); }%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, #1]
        \pgfmathsetlength{\gridstep}{\tikz@grid@x}
        \draw let \p1 = (grid start |- grid end),
        \p2 = (grid start -| grid end),
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)}
        in \pgfextra{
            \pgfmathsetlength{\gridwidth}{int(\n1 / \gridstep) * \gridstep}
            \pgfmathsetlength{\gridheight}{int(\n2 / \gridstep) * \gridstep}
            \draw[shift={(grid start)}] (0,0) grid (\gridwidth,-\gridheight);
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

%\setlength{\columnsep}{0.7cm}          % Separação entre as colunas
%\usepackage{chemformula}               % Para escrever fórmulas químicas
%\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}         % |
%\usetikzlibrary{fit}                   % |Formatação das fórmulas químicas
%\usepackage{mol2chemfig}               % |
%\usepackage{caption}                   % Colocar caption em minipage
%\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption} %Coloca a "Figura" em negrito nas legendas
%\usepackage{microtype}                     % para melhorias de justificação
%\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}    % Paginas com as citações na bibliografia
%\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}          % Citações padrão ABNT
%\usepackage{lipsum}                        % para geração de dummy text
\usepackage{subfigure}                  % Adicionar subfiguras
%\usepackage{fontawesome}               % Fonte e simbolos
\usepackage{xcolor}                     % Mudar cor das palavras
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % Inclusão de gráficos
%\hypersetup{colorlinks = true}         % Colorir Links
%\usepackage{nomencl}                   % Lista de simbolos
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
%\usepackage{showframe}                 % Mostra margens
\usepackage{amsmath}                    % Ambiente Matemático
\usepackage{array}                      % Para colocar tabelas
\usepackage{float}                      % fixa a figura no lugar
\usepackage[a]{esvect}                  % vetor pra maiuscula
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, align=left}
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}% Use this instead of \parindent = 0pt
%\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, leftmargin=15pt, labelwidth=15pt, align=left}
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}% Use this instead of \parindent = 0pt
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage[pages=all]{background}
\backgroundsetup{placement=center,angle=58,hshift=0,vshift=0,scale=8,contents={Prof. Ulisses Moreira},color=black,opacity=0.03}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pro]{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amstext}
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\color{blue}}
\usepackage{textcomp,mathcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{enumext}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumext}[list-indent=0pt,save-ans=test,show-ans=true]

    \item (Mackenzie-SP) Numa noite de inverno, o dormitório de
    Serginho apresentava uma temperatura ambiente de 10 °C. Para
    não sentir frio durante a madrugada, ele esticou sobre a cama
    três cobertores de lã bem espessos e aguardou alguns minutos.
    Em seguida, deitou-se e percebeu que a cama continuava muito
    fria. Após certo tempo na cama, bem coberto, sentiu que o “frio
    passou” e que a cama estava quente. Tal fato explica-se, pois
    %bernoulli letra b

    \begin{keyans}[label=(\alph*)]
        \item o frio não existe e a sensação de Serginho era apenas psicológica.
        \item* os cobertores não são aquecedores, mas isolantes
        térmicos. Depois de Serginho deitar-se, seu corpo aqueceu a cama. %correta
        \item a cama provavelmente não tinha lençóis de lã e,
        então, o calor produzido pelos cobertores foi perdido para
        o ambiente. Quando Serginho se deitou, interrompeu esse
        processo.
        \item os cobertores de lã provavelmente eram de cor clara
        e, por isso, demoraram muito para aquecer a cama. Após
        Serginho ter-se deitado, foi necessário mais algum tempo
        para que a cama ficasse quente.
        \item a lã utilizada para a confecção dos cobertores é um
        aquecedor natural muito lento e a temperatura de Serginho,
        de aproximadamente 37 °C, não era suficiente para aquecer a
        cama.
    \end{keyans}

    \item (FUVEST-SP) Sabe-se que a temperatura do café se mantém
    razoavelmente constante no interior de uma garrafa térmica
    perfeitamente vedada. %bernoulli
    \begin{enumext}
        \item Qual é o principal fenômeno responsável por esse bom
        isolamento térmico?
        \anskey{O espelhamento duplo das paredes dificulta a
        transferência de calor por radiação; o vácuo entre as
        paredes dificulta a transferência de calor por condução e
        convecção; a tampa inibe a transferência de calor por
        convecção e dificulta a condução de calor.}
        \item O que acontece com a temperatura do café se a garrafa
        térmica for agitada vigorosamente?

        \anskey{A energia interna e a temperatura do café aumentam.
        O café não recebe calor de fora, mas sim trabalho realizado
        pela pessoa.}
    \end{enumext}
\end{enumext}


\begin{center}
\textbf{GABARITO}
\end{center}

\printkeyans[columns=1]{test}

\end{document}


If you change the key show-and=false:

I've just formatted your code a bit and removed some whitespace, I recommend you read the package documentation.
Saludos
Second version:
Here I modified the margins a bit for a clearer output:
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1.8cm]{geometry}% Margens
\usepackage{indentfirst}                % Coloca parágrafo no início texto
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}          % Linguagem português
%\usepackage{lmodern}                   % Usa a fonte Latin Modern
\usepackage{multicol}                   % Texto em duas colunas
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\fixspacing}{\vspace{0pt plus 1filll}\mbox{}}
\usepackage{xcolor,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\gridwidth}
\newlength{\gridheight}
\newlength{\gridstep}
\newcommand{\gridfill}[1][]{%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (grid start) at (0,0); }%
    \vfill\hfill\null%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (grid end) at (0,0); }%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, #1]
        \pgfmathsetlength{\gridstep}{\tikz@grid@x}
        \draw let \p1 = (grid start |- grid end),
        \p2 = (grid start -| grid end),
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)}
        in \pgfextra{
            \pgfmathsetlength{\gridwidth}{int(\n1 / \gridstep) * \gridstep}
            \pgfmathsetlength{\gridheight}{int(\n2 / \gridstep) * \gridstep}
            \draw[shift={(grid start)}] (0,0) grid (\gridwidth,-\gridheight);
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % Mudar cor das palavras
\usepackage{amsmath}                    % Ambiente Matemático
\usepackage{array}                      % Para colocar tabelas
\usepackage{float}                      % fixa a figura no lugar
\usepackage[a]{esvect}                  % vetor pra maiuscula
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, align=left}
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage[pages=all]{background}
\backgroundsetup{placement=center,angle=58,hshift=0,vshift=0,scale=8,contents={Prof. Ulisses Moreira},color=black,opacity=0.03}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[pro]{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\color{blue}}
\usepackage{enumext}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumext}[save-ans=test,show-ans=true,widest=99,start=23]

    \item (Mackenzie-SP) Numa noite de inverno, o dormitório de
    Serginho apresentava uma temperatura ambiente de 10 °C. Para
    não sentir frio durante a madrugada, ele esticou sobre a cama
    três cobertores de lã bem espessos e aguardou alguns minutos.
    Em seguida, deitou-se e percebeu que a cama continuava muito
    fria. Após certo tempo na cama, bem coberto, sentiu que o “frio
    passou” e que a cama estava quente. Tal fato explica-se, pois
    %bernoulli letra b

    \begin{keyans}[label=(\alph*)]
        \item o frio não existe e a sensação de Serginho era apenas psicológica.
        \item* os cobertores não são aquecedores, mas isolantes
        térmicos. Depois de Serginho deitar-se, seu corpo aqueceu a cama. %correta
        \item a cama provavelmente não tinha lençóis de lã e,
        então, o calor produzido pelos cobertores foi perdido para
        o ambiente. Quando Serginho se deitou, interrompeu esse
        processo.
        \item os cobertores de lã provavelmente eram de cor clara
        e, por isso, demoraram muito para aquecer a cama. Após
        Serginho ter-se deitado, foi necessário mais algum tempo
        para que a cama ficasse quente.
        \item a lã utilizada para a confecção dos cobertores é um
        aquecedor natural muito lento e a temperatura de Serginho,
        de aproximadamente 37 °C, não era suficiente para aquecer a
        cama.
    \end{keyans}

    \item (FUVEST-SP) Sabe-se que a temperatura do café se mantém
    razoavelmente constante no interior de uma garrafa térmica
    perfeitamente vedada. %bernoulli
    \begin{enumext}
        \item Qual é o principal fenômeno responsável por esse bom
        isolamento térmico?
        \anskey{O espelhamento duplo das paredes dificulta a
        transferência de calor por radiação; o vácuo entre as
        paredes dificulta a transferência de calor por condução e
        convecção; a tampa inibe a transferência de calor por
        convecção e dificulta a condução de calor.}
        \item O que acontece com a temperatura do café se a garrafa
        térmica for agitada vigorosamente?

        \anskey{A energia interna e a temperatura do café aumentam.
        O café não recebe calor de fora, mas sim trabalho realizado
        pela pessoa.}
    \end{enumext}
\end{enumext}


\begin{center}
\textbf{GABARITO}
\end{center}

\printkeyans[widest=99,start=23,columns=1]{test}

\end{document}



I copied and pasted the code and the following error appeared during compilation. I don't know how to solve it. I'm new to latex, so I have a lot of questions.

Need TeX Live 2024 update

Is this package not available for MiKTex?

Yes it is available for MikTeX too :D

Pablo, thank you very much for the tip, it worked very well. I have one more question. In discursive questions with more than one alternative, the item responses are vertically misaligned with the rest of the responses. Is it possible to change this vertical alignment of the answers? I don't know if my question was very clear, but I couldn't post a photo.

Pablo, this is the alignment I mentioned previously. Question 24 is discursive and has three alternatives. Note that the answer to alternatives (b) and (c) are not aligned with alternative (a). I would like them to be aligned horizontally. (image).

Update answer, need widest key in \printkeyans (and enumext to)

Thanks Pablo, problem solved
